# Output variable value for attribution in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to display a string (let's say 'blabla') on the OpenLayers map such that the string's position stays constant relative to the viewfram - i.e. it does not move when the user zooms (similar to the Control.PanZoom() controls).

Control.Attribution() does this. It works for 'static' data such as

```
'attribution': "blabla"
```

However, I would also like to display strings whose value changes (let's say a variable named var, with initial value var='blabla', but whose value will also changed to 'blu' and 'pla' depending on user interaction).

I tried using

```
'attribution': "${var}"
```

but it outputs ${var} instead of 'blabla'.

Would anyone know either 1) how I could output variables with the attribution option or 2) how to place variables on the map such that it always stays in the same position relative to the viewframe?

Thank you

Comment: And using directly the variable? 'attribution': var

Comment: @fran: oh it works... somehow i missed that one. thanks :)
now my problem is that var does not get updated - i.e. it always shows 'blablabla' even after i remove the layer with the attribution, change the value of attribution, and replace the layer. Should I edit my question or ask a a new one?
PS: sorry I didn't answer earlier I didn't realise a comment was left

Comment: I think that you should open a new one to post your new problem. I'm going to post the first comment as an asnwer to help other users in the future ;)

Comment: To change the attribution, use updateAttribution http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Attribution-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.Attribution.updateAttribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use directly your variable like this:

```
var myvar = 'blabla';

// your code and then...

'attribution': myvar
```